# Segmentation fault about c++ smart pointers?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Hello I'm a fresh man to c++. And today when I test a project of my code, I encountered a problem that made me feel confused.

I want to use smart pointer in my project of parse JSON, so I pass a line of string to the class: `json_content`, and I want the member of `json_content`, `json_value` to get the string. The compiler didn't give me any warning or error, but when I run the a.out file, it tells me that `segmentation fault`. I searched a lot in Google, however I didn't find any solutions to this problem. Could any one help me? Thanks a lot! :)

BTW, my OS is `MacOSX x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0`, compiler is `Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)`

Here is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class json_content {
    public:
    string json_value;
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<json_content> c;
    shared_ptr<string> p2(new string("this is good"));

    // segmentation fault
    c->json_value = *p2;
    // this is also bad line!
    c->json_value = "not good, too!";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does `c` point to?

Comment: Side note about `shared_ptr`: Avoid using unless you really have to share ownership o f the object. There are performance concerns (a lot of neat stuff going on behind the scenes to make it share safely in a complicated and often multi-threaded world) and it tells readers to make bad assumptions about your code. It's surprising how often the second concern is worse than the first.

Comment: To complete the above comment: use `std::unique_ptr` until you find that you really need shared ownership (i.e. that there isn't a single sensible place in code that has control over it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, a `shared_ptr` is `nullptr` (see [API](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)). You can't de-reference a `nullptr`. You need to initialize `c` first:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class JsonContent {
 public:
  string json_value;
};

int main() {
  shared_ptr<JsonContent> c = std::make_shared<JsonContent>();
  shared_ptr<string> p2 = std::make_shared<string>("This is good.");

  c->json_value = *p2;
  c->json_value = "This is also good!";
  cout << c->json_value << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Demo**: http://cpp.sh/5fps7n.